# How to access counters of 'shares' with a Facebook OG object ?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have a facebook app, with an page whith its meta og tags. When I run http://graph.facebook.com/ID_Object, I get a json file with no entry for share-count but the page was shared several times. How to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling the url by id.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/?id=YourURL
```

refer to: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/#auth

> You can also request multiple objects in a single query using the
>   "ids" query parameter. For example, the URL
>   https://graph.facebook.com?ids=arjun,vernal returns both profiles in
>   the same response.
>
> The "ids" query parameter also accepts URLs. This is useful for
>   finding IDs of URLs in the Open Graph. For example:
>   https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/

**The Open Graph protocol defines four required properties:**

**og:title** - The title of your object as it should appear within the graph, e.g., "The Rock".

**og:type** - The type of your object, e.g., "movie". See the complete list of supported types.

**og:image** - An image URL which should represent your object within the graph. The image must be at least 50px by 50px (though minimum 200px by 200px is preferred) and have a maximum aspect ratio of 3:1. We support PNG, JPEG and GIF formats. You may include multiple og:image tags to associate multiple images with your page.

**og:url** - The canonical URL of your object that will be used as its permanent ID in the graph, e.g., http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/.

Comment: Thank you Shawn, now the problem is that I don't have the outputs taht should be displayed  as 'shares',etc..

Comment: can you share the url with me? I will try to debug for you.

Comment: yes here's http://primagora.org/index.php?page=campaign%26campaign_id%3D1 This page was shared 28 times but I don't find this information. Thanks so much

Comment: your url returns a 404 for me, could you check it and make sure that is the url you are trying to share please

Comment: here's in other form http://primagora.org/index.php?page=agora&op=view&post_id=1&campaign_id=1. Perhaps you'll have to login, tell me I will send my login infos

Comment: looks like you are missing og:url meta tag.  try adding that tag and rerun in the debuger, it should set the id properly and start tracking shares, likes, talking about etc;

Comment: Excuse me Shawn, I don't quite understand because the og:url I set in my page seems correct : <meta>property="og:url" content="http://primagora.org/fb/index.php?page=campaign&campaign_id=1"</meta> I don't really understand...

Comment: i am looking at the source code of the page you shared with me, no where in the source code do i see og:url

    <meta name='gwt:module' content='org.primagora=org.primagora' />
     <meta name="gwt:property" content="locale=en_US.UTF8" />
     <meta property="fb:app_id" content="218093214877796" />
     <meta property="og:site_name" content="Primagora" />

Comment: oh sorry I get it, the og url was not set really properly. Thanks for all